# How to convert AngularJS scope object into simple JS array?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

How  to convert AngularJS scope object into simple JS array?

This function checks if any checkbox is checked and adds corresponding  value to an object.
Now I want to transfer the object values to an array and alert it after press the button. But the result is undefined, why?

```js
var formApp = angular.module('formApp', [])

    .controller('formController', function($scope) {

        // we will store our form data in this object
        $scope.formData = {};
        

    });

var array = Object.keys(formData).map(function(k) { return obj[k] });

function test(){

alert(array);
}
```

```html
<-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <!-- CSS -->
    <!-- load up bootstrap and add some spacing -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
        body         { padding-top:50px; }
        form         { margin-bottom:50px; }
    </style>

    <!-- JS -->
    <!-- load up angular and our custom script -->
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<!-- apply our angular app and controller -->
<body ng-app="formApp" ng-controller="formController">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">

    <h2>Angular Checkboxes </h2>

  
...

    <!-- MULTIPLE CHECKBOXES -->
    <label>Favorite Colors</label>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" name="favoriteColors" ng-model="formData.favoriteColors.red"> Red
        </label><br>
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" name="favoriteColors" ng-model="formData.favoriteColors.blue"> Blue
        </label> <br>
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" name="favoriteColors" ng-model="formData.favoriteColors.green"> Green
        </label>
    </div>

...
    
    <!-- SHOW OFF OUR FORMDATA OBJECT -->
    <h2>formData_object_is_not_empty-test</h2>
    <pre>
       {{formData}}
    </pre>
     <button onclick="test()">Click me</button> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `formData` isn't accessible outsice of controller constructor function so when you're creating an array you're already accessing undefined. Second thing is the `obj` which is undefined as well. You should use `formData` there as well. But undelss this is an experiment this is not code that Angular apps should have... There's no *publicly* accessible code in Angular apps. Normally.

Comment: Create a function, call on ng-click of that check box, get value from that $scope variable to js object. Simple.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var formApp = angular.module('formApp', [])

.controller('formController', function($scope) {

    // we will store our form data in this object
    $scope.formData = {};
    var array = Object.keys($scope.formData).map(function(k) { return obj[k] });
    // wait for the formData to change and then alert
    setTimeout(function() {
        alert(array);
    }, 2000);


});
```

Angular is made in a way that you are not allowed to access the scope variables outside the controller.

If you want to have the array as debug information, use a browser plugin like [AngularJS Batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang-stable/niopocochgahfkiccpjmmpchncjoapek) or use `console.log(array)` instead of `alert(array)` or try to save array in a global variable with `document.array = array`, so you can access it in the browser console.